# How to return rows where there are consecutive values in different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame in pandas, where 1 appears in different columns (quarters) for every IDs (example given below). The sequence with which 1 appears is different for different IDs. I need to find out how many IDs have, lets say, 1 appeared consecutively in four columns.

```
Example data-frame:

IDs     q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6    q7    q8    q9    q10    q11   q12

1111    0     0     1     1     1      1    0     0     0     0      0     0

1122    0     0     1     0     0      1    0     0     0     0      0     0

1122    0     0     0     0     0      0    0     1     1     1      1     0
```

The result should be 2.

It would be helpful if anyone can provide the code useful in pandas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is fun way using `join` and `contains`

```
s=df.set_index('IDs').astype(str).agg(''.join,1).str.contains('1111')
s[s].index.nunique()
2
```

Comment: more creative than fun.

Answer (score 0):

I think `rolling` with `sum` also works. Howver, I don't know if it is efficient or overkill

```
df.drop('IDs', 1).rolling(window=4, axis=1).sum().eq(4).any(1).sum()

Out[89]: 2
```